# How long do arrows shot into a player take to despawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As you can see in the photo below, I have been shot be a skeleton multiple times.

[image]

How long does it take for these arrows to disappear? Is it the regular arrow despawn time of approximate 2 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a bit of testing, and it appears that the arrow consistently disappears at 580 ticks (29 seconds), which is lower than a normal arrow's despawn time of 2 minutes.

[image: Player at ticks 579 and 580]

This does not appear to be affected by the difficulty setting, or the source of the arrow (player, skeleton, dispenser).

Comment: Was this in Minecraft 1.9? Also thank you for the testing!

Comment: @techydesigner Minecraft 1.10.